# fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git помогите

Tags: git

```bash
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
        -1.14-windows.xml
        .android/
        .bash_history
        .cache/
        .git-for-windows-updater
        .gradle/
        .idlerc/
        .matplotlib/
        .node_repl_history
        3D Objects/
        AppData/
        AppMods/
        Application Data/
        Contacts/
        Cookies/
        Desktop/
        Documents/
        Downloads/
        Favorites/
        Links/
        Local Settings/
        Music/
        NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TM.blf
        NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
        NTUSER.DAT{53b39e88-18c4-11ea-a811-000d3aa4692b}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
        Pictures/
        Recent/
        Recorded Calls/
        Saved Games/
        Searches/
        SendTo/
        Videos/
        liggghts/
        ntuser.dat
        ntuser.dat.log1
        ntuser.dat.log2
        ntuser.dat{96490745-dd8b-11ee-bac1-ac220bdb7db5}.TM.blf
        ntuser.dat{96490745-dd8b-11ee-bac1-ac220bdb7db5}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
        ntuser.dat{96490745-dd8b-11ee-bac1-ac220bdb7db5}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
        ntuser.dat{97e718a5-c423-11ee-ba75-ac220bdb7db5}.TM.blf
        ntuser.dat{97e718a5-c423-11ee-ba75-ac220bdb7db5}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
        ntuser.dat{97e718a5-c423-11ee-ba75-ac220bdb7db5}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
        ntuser.ini
        sblauncher.json
        "\320\234\320\276\320\270 \320\264\320\276\320\272\321\203\320\274\320\265\320\275\321\202\321\213/"
        "\320\263\320\273\320\260\320\262\320\275\320\276\320\265 \320\274\320\265\320\275\321\216/"

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)


$ git clone git://cfdem.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/cfdem/liggghts

$ git init
```

Comment: You've added a git repo to your user folder. Consider removing it? You didn't need to run `git init` after cloning

Answer (score 0):

There are two different things here.

1. Clone an existing repository:

```bash
$ git clone git://cfdem.git.sourceforge.net/gitroot/cfdem/liggghts
$ cd liggghts
$ git status
```

2. Create a new repository:

```bash
$ mkdir myproject && cd $_
$ git init
$ git status
```